# No webrtcdsp on macOS

Tags: macos, webrtc, gstreamer

I am developing a Voip apps using gstreamer on MAC, and I need echo canceler for audio. One is recomended webrtcdsp, but I can't find it in gst-inspect. I tried compile from source but the problem is the same. Can someone knows what kind of library I need to use for proper compile to use webrtcdsp?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `gst-plugins-bad`, should solve it. 
It is a part of `libgstwebrtcdsp.so` library.

Comment: I tried it, installed from _brew_, then compiled from source and still the same

Comment: which version of gstreamer are you using. It's available in version 1.14.1.

Comment: I use gstreamer 1.14.2

Comment: if `gst-inspect <element_name>`, does not show your element, that means the plugin is not installed correctly. Try using  `apt-get` and install the plugins.

Comment: yes I can't find the element with _gst-inspect_ tool. I can't use apt-get, because I'm in apple macOS platform